# Is it possible to develop for 10.7 and 10.8 using xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am developing OS X app which has GUI as well so designer will be used as well. The app in addition to latest OS X versions must support older platforms such as 10.8 and 10.7 Does xcode 6 support this out of the box if not, what are the steps involved to achieve it ?
Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Xcode 6 to develop an app that targets 10.7 with no problem.

The Deployment Target dropdown lets you select all the way down to 10.4.

Comment: Thanks Eirc, I was under the impression that newer xcode does have old sdk frameworks etc. I am setting it up now ..

Answer (score 0):

In the build settings, set the deployment version (not the SDK version) to 10.7.